# SQL Query about a column heading

Tags: sql

I am currently creating a query in SQL where I need to produce a list of customers with no current car sales in the Car For Sale table.
My code so far is below:

```
SELECT 
  Customer.CustomerCode, CarForSale.CustomerCode
FROM 
  Customer LEFT JOIN CarForSale
  ON Customer.CustomerCode = CarForSale.CustomerCode
WHERE 
  CarForSale.CustomerCode IS NULL;
```

The problem I am having is that the correct customer codes are displayed that are not in the Car for Sale table, however I need to display the Column heading as 'CustomerCode'.

Does anyone know what I could add to produce this?

Comment: you may be looking for `left outer join`

Comment: @DanPichelman `LEFT OUTER JOIN == LEFT JOIN`

Comment: doh!  I actually knew that.

Comment: Please post the expected result.  If you're just concerned with the heading on the output you can always assign a column `alias` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Dan. That works. The column being displayed is 'Customer.CustomerCode', and I want it to just be 'CustomerCode'. You wouldn't happen to know how I do this by any chance do you?

Comment: @PM77-1 Cheers, Where would I add that?

Comment: @Alyn - `SELECT Customer.CustomerCode As "Customer Code" ...` (or something similar depending on the exact flavor of SQL you're using).  Arran posted it with MS SQL syntax below.

Comment: OK thank you everyone for your help, I've got it now :)

Comment: Why do you select the CustomerCode twice? If there is a match, both values will be identical, if there isn't you *know* the second one will be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerCode As [CustomerCode], CarForSale.CustomerCode
FROM Customer 
LEFT JOIN CarForSale ON Customer.CustomerCode = CarForSale.CustomerCode 
WHERE CarForSale.CustomerCode IS NULL
```

would work. (If using T-SQL)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
SELECT 
  Customer.CustomerCode CustomerCodeA, CarForSale.CustomerCode CustomerCodeB
FROM 
  Customer LEFT JOIN CarForSale
  ON Customer.CustomerCode = CarForSale.CustomerCode
)
WHERE 
  CustomerCodeB IS NULL;
```

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed the part where you said the column heading needs to be CustomerCode... however it is confusing to have two columns with the same name.

Comment: The subQuery is not necessary.